# How to add to a tuple

Tags: python, html, tuples

I have a tuple that passes 3 items to an HTML page, and I want it to pass a fourth. I've read online that to do that, I'd have to turn my tuple into a list, but I tried that, and still didn't get anything (no errors, the objects just didn't show up at the end). So I stashed it for clarity.

I'm trying to add "maybe_existing_user.fb_pic" to the "details" tuple.

**PYTHON**

```
@app.route('/results/<int:id>')
def results(id):
    rate = 0  # either 0 or num/total
    article_list_of_one = Article.query.filter_by(id=id)
    a_obj = article_list_of_one[0]

    avs_obj = retrieve_article_vote_summary(a_obj.id) # vote_summary is a list of [tuples('True', numOfTrue), etc]
    total_votes = avs_obj.getTotalVotes()
    vote_choices = []
    vote_choice_list = VoteChoice.getVoteChoiceList()
    for item in vote_choice_list: # looping over VoteChoice objects
        num = avs_obj.getVoteCount(item.choice)
        if total_votes > 0:        # protecting against no votes
            rate = num/total_votes 
        vote_choices.append([item.choice, item.color, num, rate*100, total_votes])

    details = avs_obj.getVoteDetails() # 10/02 - retrieve array of tuples [(user, VoteChoice, Comments)]
    print("Inside results(" + str(id) + "):")
    details_count = 0
    for detail in details:

        maybe_existing_user = User.query.filter_by(name=detail[0]).first()
        detail += (maybe_existing_user.fb_pic,)

        print(detail)
        #print("    " + str(details_count) + ": " + details[0] + " " + details[1] + " " + details[2])
        details_count += 1

    return render_template('results.html', title=a_obj.title, id=id,
                           image_url=a_obj.image_url, url=a_obj.url,
                           vote_choices=vote_choices, home_data=Article.query.all(),
                           vote_details=details)
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
{% for detail in vote_details %}
<strong>User:</strong> {{ detail[0] }} &nbsp; <strong>Vote:</strong> {{ detail[1] }} &nbsp; <strong>Comments:</strong> {{ detail[2] }}<br>
{{ detail[3] }}
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new 'details' list of tuples. In Python, you often can not change lists "in place". If you just create a new 'detail' inside the for-loop, it will not get passed on to the 'details' list.

So, you need to replace the complete loop `for detail in details:` by the following line:

```py
updated_details = [(user, VoteChoice, Comments, User.query.filter_by(name=user).first().fb_pic)
                   for (user, VoteChoice, Comments) in details]
```

At the end, you use these updated details to the returned render_template:

```
return render_template(..., vote_details=updated_details)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to replace 'detail[0]' with 'user'

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are immutable, so you cannot modify them directly.

Inside your for loop, make a list out of the original `detail` tuple, and append to that the additional value. Then, you can convert the list back to a tuple:

```
detail_list = list(detail)
detail_list += [maybe_existing_user.fb_pic]
detail = tuple(detail_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be almost working, but it's adding the last item letter by letter? Here's my console printing out the new list:('Name', 'Exaggerated', 'comment', 'h', 't', 't', 'p', 's', ':', '/', '/', 'p', 'l', 'a', 't', 'f', 'o', 'r', 'm', '-', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'k', 'a', 's', 'i', 'd', 'e', '.', 'f', 'b', 's', 'b', 'x', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm', '/', 'p', 'l', 'a', 't', 'f', 'o', 'r', 'm', '/', 'p', 'r', 'o', 'f', 'i', 'l', 'e', 'p', 'i', 'c', '/', '?', 'a', 's', 'i', 'd', '=', '1', '0', '2', '0', '0', '9', '1', '3', '3', '8', '2', '6', '5', '3', '7', '8', '2', '&', )

Comment: Letter by letter -- perhaps because strings are iterables / sequences in Python. Updated my answer with a string example.

Comment: That worked for the console print! Though it's still not showing up on the HTML. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: @IlanaE.Strauss Well, that's explained in my answer. Changing one detail tuple doesn't help in what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Repacking in one line with the splat operator

```
detail_list = *detail_list, maybe_existing_user.fb_pic
```

For example, in a python3 shell:

```
>>> detail_list = ("cat", "dog")
>>> detail_list = *detail_list, "rabbit"
>>> detail_list
('cat', 'dog', 'rabbit')
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already adding to the tuple correctly. The problem is that `detail += ...` creates a new tuple rather than appending to the existing one in the `details` list (because tuples are immutable). When you `print(detail)` within the loop, it seems to be altered correctly, but if you were to print the whole list `details` you would see the tuples in there do not have the additional information.

One solution is to rebuild the details list with the new tuples.

```
def add_more_info(t):
    maybe_existing_user = User.query.filter_by(name=detail[0]).first()
    return t + (maybe_existing_user, )

details = [add_more_info(detail) for detail in details]
```

Another solution would be to convert all of the details to lists first. Then you can append to them.

```
details = [list(detail) for detail in details]
for detail in details:
    maybe_existing_user = User.query.filter_by(name=detail[0]).first()
    detail.append(maybe_existing_user)
```